# Possible to force the client to try the next A record after PHP interpreter starts?

Tags: php, dns, nameservers

My suspicion is that once a connecion has been accepted, this is not possible, but I do mot have enough knowledge of browser implementations or DNS standards to be sure. The question is, once the client (web visitor) has established a connection with a resolved web server, can a PHP script on that server be used to force the client to attempt to connect to the next available A record (as though the server had never been reachable or acknowledged the request to begin with)?

I would prefer to stay away from redirects, unless it is somehow possible to determine the order of A records received by the client in the round robin DNS configuration (which I don't believe the server could possibly be aware of).

Comment: Not in PHP but via a load balance see [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)

Comment: @Baba if my understanding is correct, the load balancer is also unaware of the A record sorting... It just distributes incoming traffic across the nodes in its cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process of browser-DNS interactions:

(I'll pass the query to the TLD's which does not matter here)

The browser ask to the DNS of the domain to visit the right IP.

The DNS decides which IP it will send to the browser based on it's own internal rules.

The DNS answer to the browser "this domain have this IP"

There is no way to "influence" the DNS ever.

So no, you cannot "jump" to another server once the communication have started and the TCP/IP channel is open.

Now, if you want to do this, you will have no other way than using 301 or 302 redirects

And again, if you have to do this I guess your load balancing is surely wrongly configured.

The DNS load balancer *should* know the rules for IP dispachting *before* you distach them. If that not happen, you are misconfigured, or have not installed or programmed what you have to.

Comment: I am referring to the situation in which multiple A records are configured for a site, in which case multiple IP addresses are returned to the client, not just one as indicated above. Also, I did not make any mention of load balancing in the question. That said, if the rest of the response is correct, this seems to confirm my suspicion that skipping the current A record is not possible post-connection.

Comment: Efectively, the selection of the IP is made "before" opening the sesion to the server, not after. Having multiple IP in a DNS for a domain is the simplest load balancing technology when you cannot have a load balancer (software or hardware) dedicated

Comment: thanks for the input, but I'm not talking about load balancing here. Round robin DNS can certainly be used as a simplistic approach to load balancing (albeit without any pertinent load information, most of the time), but that's tertiary to the question.